Can't access hook in a function
I was trying to access a hook that i created into another function (function handleValidation) but that hook and its values were not available. When I tried to check if the function was working using a alert (example :alert(password)) I got the value for password as "undefined"  .....help please


 const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });



  // Handling change
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ values,[event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };


    // Submit functionality
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      handleValidation();
    };



  // Validating form
  const handleValidation = () => {
    const { password,confirmPassword,username, email } = values;
      console.log(password)
    
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      console.log("Match", toast);
      toast.error(
        "Password and confirm password should be same.",
        toastOptions
      );
      return false;
    } else if (username === "") {
      toast.error(
        "Username should be greater than 3 characters.",
        toastOptions
      );
      return false;
    } else if (password.length < 8) {
      toast.error(
        "Password should be equal or greater than 8 characters.",
        toastOptions
      );
      return false;
    } else if (email === "") {
      toast.error("Email is required.", toastOptions);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

I am trying to check if the credentials entered in the form meet certain rules,

The issue in handleChange
Solution
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setValues({ ...values,[event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}

You forgot to add spread operator before values
More Explain

For example when you type h in the username input using your code, handleChange function will run and update values object, BUT not as you expected. When you console.log values:
{
  values: {
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  },
  username: "h",
}

and after typing one more character it will be a big mess:
{
  values: {
    values: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: ""
    },
    username: "h"
  },
  username: "hh",
}

and it will get worse, and that is why you could not find password inside the values object.

Thanks for your help. I tried your code and now it is working fine.

@SiddheshJagdale Great! don't forget to mark my answer as accepted to help me and other people with same problem, thanks
